# Unable to test Sendgrid locally with HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, sendgrid

I'm trying to do a basic test with Sendgrid but I keep getting 403 and 401 with my requests.

I'm doing the testing with the localhost development server to simulate a request to my endpoint. My sendgrid key is stored in .env like the rest of my keys as sendgrid_api_key. My API key has full access to sendgrid. I have installed sendgrid==6.9.7

```
import os
import sendgrid

def sendgrid_welcome_email(request):
    try:
        
        sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(api_key=os.environ.get('sendgrid_api_key'))
    
        response = sg.client.contactdb.lists.get()
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.body)
        print(response.headers)


    except Exception as ex:
        print("Unexpected error: " + str(ex))
        return "Bad", 500
```

> Error "Unexpected error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden"

Comment: Sendgrid old docs! - new endpoint is "client.marketing.contacts"

Comment: Got it thanks will adjust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved it by using another client endpoint, I think the docs I looked at were old.

```
import os
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient


sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))

data = {
    "contacts": [
        {
            "email": "ryan39@lee-young.com"
          
        }
    ]
}

response = sg.client.marketing.contacts.put(
    request_body=data
)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.body)
print(response.headers)
```